# ld: library not found for -lboost IOS

Tags: ios

I have create one application in which I try to Run the application, it show me following error.The code written on C++. This library not found to search.
ld: library not found for -lboost
clang: 
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: How did you install boost?  Where did you install it?  What are the Xcode/Makefile settings?

Comment: I can install boost file through github

Comment: https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost

Comment: OK did you read the *How To Link to an Xcode Project?* bit on that page?

Comment: this file not found in xcode7 Add to 'Link Binary With Libraries' the libboost.a found in the ofxiOSBoost/libs/boost/lib/ios directory.

Comment: This file not found on xcode7....Add to 'Link Binary With Libraries' the libboost.a found in the ofxiOSBoost/libs/boost/lib/ios directory.

Comment: also not found this on xcode7..In Xcode for a Build Target select the Target under Build Phases